# SharePoint client object model in a web part thrown 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint

Can I use SharePoint client object model in web part?

This code works in my console application, but in a web part it returns "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

The code is:

```
var siteUrl = "http://www.server.com/";
var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

var root = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
WebCollection collWeb = root.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
clientContext.Load(root);
clientContext.Load(collWeb);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The problem might be that the client context does not use the current user credentials. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add credentials to the clientContext:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential cr = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

clientContext.Credentials = cr;
```

Comment: You can also pass the domain as a third parameter to the NetworkCredential constructor.

Comment: Thanks, it works! One more question: the web part is running in SharePoint. How do I use the credentials of the current user? Can I say something like:

    clientContexrt.Credentials = CurrentUser.Credentials;

Comment: Great.  Please accept the answer.  :).  For your next question are you using SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Check this link.  Let me know if that works for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441794/retrieve-current-user-login-in-sharepoint-from-a-silverlight-application

Comment: It doesn't work: I have to use var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl); where siteUrl is a remote site whereas in the link you specifid, it uses ClientContext clientContext = ClientContext.Current;

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

to get credential of current user

but, if you are calling a remote sharepoint server, i'm afraid it will NOT works because the [double hop problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx)

the way to call remote sharepoint as CURRENT USER is using ECMA Client Object Model...

of course, the user must allready logedin